# Run time error 3144 from UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Transaction SET receipt_id=" & txtreceipt_id & ", tdate=" & txttdate & ",total_cost=" & txttotal_cost & ",total_disc=" & txttotal_disc & " WHERE receipt_id=" & txtreceipt_id & " "
```

I get a run time 3144 syntax error. Can't seem to locate the error.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the complete syntax error?

Comment: Do you need some extra quotes? Start using CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Transaction SET receipt_id=" & txtreceipt_id and add the other fields one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [parameterized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) with MS Access' [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) to accurately specify the data types of your binded values and avoid concatenation and quote wrapping which renders hard to maintain code. Adjust below types as needed in `PARAMETERS` clause (compliant in Access SQL).

**SQL** *(save as an MS Access stored query only once)*

```
PARAMETERS [txtreceipt_id_PARAM] LONG, [txttdate_PARAM] DATE,
           [txttotal_cost_PARAM] DOUBLE, [txttotal_disc_PARAM] DOUBLE;
UPDATE [Transaction] 
SET receipt_id = [txtreceipt_id_PARAM], 
    tdate = [txttdate_PARAM],
    total_cost = [txttotal_cost_PARAM], 
    total_disc = [txttotal_disc_PARAM]
WHERE receipt_id = [txtreceipt_id_PARAM];
```

**VBA** *(dynamically bind values to parameter placeholders)*

```vb
Dim qdef as QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef![txtreceipt_id_PARAM] = txtreceipt_id
qdef![txttdate_PARAM] = txttdate
qdef![txttotal_cost_PARAM] = txttotal_cost
qdef![txttotal_disc_PARAM] = txttotal_disc

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't know about the query defs.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like the syntax is a little off... It might help to split up the code into pieces... I wasn't able to test this solution but try this (It all depends on the datatype):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Transaction " & _
" SET receipt_id = '" & txtreceipt_id & "'" & _
", tdate = "  & txttdate & "" & _
", total_cost = " & txttotal_cost & "" & _
", total_disc = " & txttotal_disc & "" & _
" WHERE receipt_id = '" & txtreceipt_id & "'"
```

If txreceipt_id is a number then try:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Transaction " & _
" SET receipt_id = " & txtreceipt_id & "" & _
", tdate = " & txttdate & "" & _
", total_cost = " & txttotal_cost & "" & _
", total_disc = " & txttotal_disc & "" & _
" WHERE receipt_id = " & txtreceipt_id & ""
```

Comment: It's probably txttdate which is in need of single quotes. Also `& "" ` seems pointless.